# CSS: Target an element on hover OR focus, but not both

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm using [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) to create a simple dropdown list.

The user should be able to use the down key to scroll through suggestions, and be able to use the mouse to select a suggestion. The suggestions should be appropriately highlighted in either of these scenarios.

The problem I'm having is achieving the above without highlighting both hovered states AND when scrolling using the down/up arrows.

This can be seen clearly in the gif below.

[image]

To highlight hovered states I'm using:

```
.tt-suggestion:hover {
  color: #f0f0f0;
  background-color: #0097cf;
}
```

And to highlight elements scrolled to with down/up arrows I'm using:

```
.tt-cursor {
  color: #f0f0f0;
  background-color: #0097cf;
}
```

*Note:* `.tt-cursor` is a class that is automatically appended to the suggestion div when scrolled to, and then removed when scrolled away from.

Here's a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/james7786789869/pen/vYEbpLN) to get a better idea of what's happening.

I'm using a rails backend, and handling most of this with Javascript & jQuery.

**Edit**: For clarification. I want to only highlight a suggestion when hovered OR scrolled to, instead of when hovered AND scrolled to (to avoid having more than one suggestion highlighted at one time).

Comment: Yet the meaning is clear with the dual highlight: one high-light shows what is selected using the keyboard, the other highlight shows what might be selected if they would click using the mouse. Maybe better differentiate in colour to make that distinction clearer. The highlight of the hover is not yet a selection, where the keyboard immediately affects the text-box (and thus makes the selection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you need and just remove the hover css

```
/* .tt-suggestion:hover {
    color: #f0f0f0;
    background-color: #0097cf;
} */

  $('div').on("mouseover",'.tt-suggestion',function(){

    $('.tt-selectable').removeClass('tt-cursor')
    $('.tt-selectable').css( "color", '')
    $('.tt-selectable').css( "background-color", '')
    $(this).css( "color", '#f0f0f0')
    $(this).css( "background-color", '#0097cf')
  })
  document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {

    e = e || window.event;


    if (e.keyCode == '40') {
      $('.tt-selectable').css( "color", '')
      $('.tt-selectable').css( "background-color", '')
    }
   if (e.keyCode == '38') {
      $('.tt-selectable').css( "color", '')
     $('.tt-selectable').css( "background-color", '')
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you modify my CodePen to show this working? I'm unsure how to implement.

Comment: i have checked in your coedpen and it was working like charm

Comment: just use it below  
var sample = ['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'aaaa'];

Comment: where were you using it just put the same code below

var sample = ['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'aaaa'];

Comment: Yep, I put your code snippet below var sample, the result stays the same. You could create a codepen, but remember to include jquery and typeahead libraries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206518/discussion-between-nextstep-and-ravi).

Comment: i have updated my answer just use it below var sample = ['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'aaaa'];

Comment: this is your codepen link

https://codepen.io/rk2006/pen/xxbMWxP

Comment: i have updated my answer please check and upvote it if it helped

Comment: This action  open space for bug. Because if you have a cursor in an Item and don't move the cursor and use the arrow, how this work?

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what effect you want to achieve, but if you want to somehow visually show that element is both selected and hovered over, you should target both those conditions like this

```
.tt-cursor.tt-suggestion:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I edited the question to improve clarification. This solution works for your use case but unfortunately isn't what I'm looking for.